# Get openAPI.json with Swagger and Next.js

Tags: next.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I want to generate openapi.json along with the swagger endpoint. I'm using `next-swagger-doc` to write swagger specifications, but want to add openapi.json file link in the swagger. The version I'm using is OpenAPI 3.0.

The link can be seen here, below the title and base url, the link to the swagger file
https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml

I tried on searching for the tag, but couldn't find it, and it's in swagger 2.0/OAS 2.0. Any idea how I could add the same in OAS 3.0?